# Python - tkinter Treeview not updating integer variable

Tags: python, tkinter

The first set of code works. It displays the updating variable. However, in the second code, when I put the variable in a Treeview widget instead, the variable just stays on 0 and does not update. How come this works with the label but not with treeview? What is the easiest way to fix this?

First (works):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

def fun():
    for i in range(10):
        var.set(var.get() + 1)
        time.sleep(.5)

t = threading.Thread(target=fun)

root = Tk()

var = IntVar()
var.set(0)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
label = ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=var)
label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

t.start()
root.mainloop()
```

Second (does not work):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

def fun():
    for i in range(10):
        var.set(var.get() + 1)
        time.sleep(.5)

t = threading.Thread(target=fun)

root = Tk()

var = IntVar()
var.set(0)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

tree = ttk.Treeview(mainframe, columns = ('number'), height = 1)

tree.insert('', 'end', text = 'Number', values = var.get())
tree.grid(column=0, row=0)

t.start()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify `fun` to :

```
def fun():
    for i in range(10):
        var.set(var.get() + 1)
        x = tree.get_children()
        tree.item(x, text = 'Number', values = var.get())
        time.sleep(.5)
```

The **get_children** method returns a list of tuples item IDs, one for each child of the tree. With **tree.item** then **update the child** with the required id.

In the second program along with the variable `var`, you also have to update the child of the tree

Comment: Thanks. How come the value doesn't update automatically like the first example?

Comment: How come i have to update each child of the tree when in the first example has the label changing automatically? When I receive a new piece of data from my streaming data source I was hoping to not have to update all the children as many of the values may not have changed.

Comment: @AndrewK, whatever you insert into a tree automatically makes it a child of the tree. [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html) may help for better understanding.